# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout in Android 10

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, androidx, layout-inflater

I opened an old Android project and I fixed most of the errors and right now I have just one which appears only on Android 10 devices:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17 in :layout/abc_screen_simple: Binary XML file line #17 in :layout/abc_screen_simple: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.FitWindowsLinearLayout
```

I found some tips about upgrading calligraphy and viewpump, but these dependencies are not included in my project and adding them does not solve the problem either.
Here are my dependencies:

```
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.4'
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation('com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-simplexml:2.9.0') {
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
}
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:17.0.0'
implementation('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
    exclude module: 'stax-api'
}
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
implementation 'com.bpodgursky:jbool_expressions:1.14'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.2'
implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar+'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
implementation('com.foursquare:foursquare-android-oauth:1.0.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android'
}
implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'logging-interceptor', version: '4.8.1'
implementation group: 'com.github.ganfra', name: 'material-spinner', version: '2.0.0'

implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.2.4'
implementation 'com.github.bmarrdev:android-DecoView-charting:v1.2'
implementation 'com.xw.repo:bubbleseekbar:3.15-lite'
implementation 'pl.edu.wat.wcy.iqpharma:shared:1.62'
implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
implementation group: 'com.github.ozodrukh', name: 'CircularReveal', version: '2.0.1'

implementation group: 'com.mikepenz', name: 'iconics-core', version: '3.2.1'
implementation group: 'com.mikepenz', name: 'material-design-iconic-typeface', version: '2.2.0.5'
implementation group: 'com.mikepenz', name: 'fontawesome-typeface', version: '5.3.1.1'

implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.andrognito.pinlockview:pinlockview:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem. I was using font awesome (com.mikepenz) and that is why it did not work:

```
IconicsContextWrapper.wrap(newBase)
```